# How to represent a data list by arrows?

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a code that builds a plot with 7 functions and mark 4 points. Each level of list data describes a function (see below).
The curves are created from the "data" input from `ListLinePlot`. The points e0, e1, e2, and e3 are created from `Graphics`.

```
e0={0,0};
e1={0.230769, 0};
e2={0, 0.230769};
e3={0.104895, 0.104895};
data= {{{0.1, 0.1}, {0.1014, 0.1014}, {0.102414, 0.102414}, {0.10314, 
   0.10314}, {0.103658, 0.103658}, {0.104025, 0.104025}, {0.104284, 
   0.104284}, {0.104466, 0.104466}, {0.104594, 0.104594}, {0.104684, 
   0.104684}, {0.104747, 0.104747}, {0.104792, 0.104792}, {0.104823, 
   0.104823}, {0.104844, 0.104844}, {0.10486, 0.10486}, {0.10487, 
   0.10487}, {0.104878, 0.104878}, {0.104883, 0.104883}, {0.104887, 
   0.104887}, {0.104889, 0.104889}, {0.104891, 0.104891}, {0.104892, 
   0.104892}, {0.104893, 0.104893}, {0.104894, 0.104894}, {0.104894, 
   0.104894}, {0.104894, 0.104894}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}}, {{0.1, 0.2}, {0.0858, 
   0.1768}, {0.0783055, 0.16554}, {0.0736041, 0.159356}, {0.0703449, 
   0.155852}, {0.0679125, 0.153928}, {0.0659829, 
   0.152997}, {0.0643694, 0.152717}, {0.0629585, 
   0.152878}, {0.0616782, 0.153343}, {0.0604819, 
   0.154023}, {0.0593386, 0.154858}, {0.0582279, 0.155805}, {0.057136,
    0.156836}, {0.0560538, 0.157931}, {0.0549752, 
   0.159075}, {0.0538963, 0.160259}, {0.0528147, 
   0.161474}, {0.0517288, 0.162717}, {0.0506381, 
   0.163981}, {0.0495423, 0.165265}, {0.0484415, 
   0.166566}, {0.0473363, 0.167881}, {0.0462272, 
   0.169209}, {0.0451149, 0.170548}, {0.0440004, 
   0.171897}, {0.0428845, 0.173254}, {0.0417685, 
   0.174617}, {0.0406532, 0.175986}, {0.0395398, 
   0.177359}, {0.0384295, 0.178733}, {0.0373234, 
   0.180109}, {0.0362227, 0.181484}, {0.0351286, 
   0.182857}, {0.0340423, 0.184225}, {0.032965, 0.185589}, {0.0318978,
    0.186945}, {0.0308419, 0.188293}, {0.0297985, 
   0.189631}, {0.0287686, 0.190957}, {0.0277532, 
   0.192271}, {0.0267535, 0.193569}, {0.0257704, 
   0.194851}, {0.0248048, 0.196116}, {0.0238576, 
   0.197362}, {0.0229295, 0.198588}, {0.0220214, 
   0.199793}, {0.0211338, 0.200975}, {0.0202674, 
   0.202133}, {0.0194228, 0.203267}, {0.0186003, 
   0.204375}, {0.0178004, 0.205458}, {0.0170233, 
   0.206513}, {0.0162693, 0.207541}, {0.0155386, 0.20854}, {0.0148313,
    0.209512}, {0.0141473, 0.210454}, {0.0134866, 
   0.211367}, {0.0128491, 0.212252}, {0.0122347, 
   0.213107}, {0.0116432, 0.213932}, {0.0110742, 
   0.214729}, {0.0105274, 0.215497}, {0.0100025, 
   0.216237}, {0.00949902, 0.216948}, {0.00901659, 
   0.217631}, {0.00855471, 0.218287}, {0.00811287, 
   0.218916}, {0.00769055, 0.219519}, {0.00728721, 
   0.220096}, {0.00690228, 0.220648}, {0.00653519, 
   0.221175}, {0.00618537, 0.221679}, {0.00585223, 
   0.222159}, {0.00553517, 0.222618}, {0.00523362, 
   0.223055}, {0.00494698, 0.22347}, {0.00467467, 
   0.223866}, {0.00441613, 0.224243}, {0.00417077, 
   0.2246}, {0.00393804, 0.22494}, {0.00371741, 
   0.225263}, {0.00350833, 0.225569}, {0.00331029, 
   0.225859}, {0.00312278, 0.226135}, {0.00294532, 
   0.226395}, {0.00277742, 0.226643}, {0.00261862, 
   0.226876}, {0.00246849, 0.227098}, {0.0023266, 
   0.227307}, {0.00219253, 0.227505}, {0.0020659, 
   0.227692}, {0.00194631, 0.227869}, {0.00183341, 
   0.228037}, {0.00172685, 0.228194}, {0.0016263, 
   0.228344}, {0.00153144, 0.228484}, {0.00144196, 
   0.228617}, {0.00135758, 0.228742}, {0.00127803, 
   0.228861}, {0.00120303, 0.228972}}, {{0.1, 0.8}, {0, 0.0832}, {0, 
   0.100173}, {0, 0.118619}, {0, 0.137882}, {0, 0.157115}, {0, 
   0.175399}, {0, 0.191902}, {0, 0.20603}, {0, 0.217509}, {0, 
   0.226373}, {0, 0.232885}, {0, 0.23743}, {0, 0.240425}, {0, 
   0.242252}, {0, 0.243233}, {0, 0.243621}, {0, 0.243607}, {0, 
   0.243329}, {0, 0.242885}, {0, 0.242344}, {0, 0.241754}, {0, 
   0.241144}, {0, 0.240536}, {0, 0.239943}, {0, 0.239373}, {0, 
   0.23883}, {0, 0.238316}, {0, 0.237832}, {0, 0.237378}, {0, 
   0.236953}, {0, 0.236555}, {0, 0.236184}, {0, 0.235837}, {0, 
   0.235513}, {0, 0.235211}, {0, 0.234928}, {0, 0.234665}, {0, 
   0.234419}, {0, 0.234189}, {0, 0.233974}, {0, 0.233773}, {0, 
   0.233586}, {0, 0.23341}, {0, 0.233246}, {0, 0.233092}, {0, 
   0.232948}, {0, 0.232813}, {0, 0.232687}, {0, 0.232569}, {0, 
   0.232458}, {0, 0.232355}, {0, 0.232257}, {0, 0.232166}, {0, 
   0.232081}, {0, 0.232001}, {0, 0.231926}, {0, 0.231855}, {0, 
   0.231789}, {0, 0.231727}, {0, 0.231669}, {0, 0.231614}, {0, 
   0.231563}, {0, 0.231515}, {0, 0.231469}, {0, 0.231427}, {0, 
   0.231387}, {0, 0.23135}, {0, 0.231315}, {0, 0.231282}, {0, 
   0.231251}, {0, 0.231222}, {0, 0.231194}, {0, 0.231169}, {0, 
   0.231145}, {0, 0.231122}, {0, 0.231101}, {0, 0.231081}, {0, 
   0.231062}, {0, 0.231044}, {0, 0.231028}, {0, 0.231012}, {0, 
   0.230998}, {0, 0.230984}, {0, 0.230971}, {0, 0.230959}, {0, 
   0.230947}, {0, 0.230937}, {0, 0.230927}, {0, 0.230917}, {0, 
   0.230908}, {0, 0.2309}, {0, 0.230892}, {0, 0.230885}, {0, 
   0.230878}, {0, 0.230871}, {0, 0.230865}, {0, 0.230859}, {0, 
   0.230854}, {0, 0.230849}, {0, 0.230844}}, {{0.2, 0.1}, {0.1768, 
   0.0858}, {0.16554, 0.0783055}, {0.159356, 0.0736041}, {0.155852, 
   0.0703449}, {0.153928, 0.0679125}, {0.152997, 
   0.0659829}, {0.152717, 0.0643694}, {0.152878, 
   0.0629585}, {0.153343, 0.0616782}, {0.154023, 
   0.0604819}, {0.154858, 0.0593386}, {0.155805, 
   0.0582279}, {0.156836, 0.057136}, {0.157931, 0.0560538}, {0.159075,
    0.0549752}, {0.160259, 0.0538963}, {0.161474, 
   0.0528147}, {0.162717, 0.0517288}, {0.163981, 
   0.0506381}, {0.165265, 0.0495423}, {0.166566, 
   0.0484415}, {0.167881, 0.0473363}, {0.169209, 
   0.0462272}, {0.170548, 0.0451149}, {0.171897, 
   0.0440004}, {0.173254, 0.0428845}, {0.174617, 
   0.0417685}, {0.175986, 0.0406532}, {0.177359, 
   0.0395398}, {0.178733, 0.0384295}, {0.180109, 
   0.0373234}, {0.181484, 0.0362227}, {0.182857, 
   0.0351286}, {0.184225, 0.0340423}, {0.185589, 0.032965}, {0.186945,
    0.0318978}, {0.188293, 0.0308419}, {0.189631, 
   0.0297985}, {0.190957, 0.0287686}, {0.192271, 
   0.0277532}, {0.193569, 0.0267535}, {0.194851, 
   0.0257704}, {0.196116, 0.0248048}, {0.197362, 
   0.0238576}, {0.198588, 0.0229295}, {0.199793, 
   0.0220214}, {0.200975, 0.0211338}, {0.202133, 
   0.0202674}, {0.203267, 0.0194228}, {0.204375, 
   0.0186003}, {0.205458, 0.0178004}, {0.206513, 
   0.0170233}, {0.207541, 0.0162693}, {0.20854, 0.0155386}, {0.209512,
    0.0148313}, {0.210454, 0.0141473}, {0.211367, 
   0.0134866}, {0.212252, 0.0128491}, {0.213107, 
   0.0122347}, {0.213932, 0.0116432}, {0.214729, 
   0.0110742}, {0.215497, 0.0105274}, {0.216237, 
   0.0100025}, {0.216948, 0.00949902}, {0.217631, 
   0.00901659}, {0.218287, 0.00855471}, {0.218916, 
   0.00811287}, {0.219519, 0.00769055}, {0.220096, 
   0.00728721}, {0.220648, 0.00690228}, {0.221175, 
   0.00653519}, {0.221679, 0.00618537}, {0.222159, 
   0.00585223}, {0.222618, 0.00553517}, {0.223055, 
   0.00523362}, {0.22347, 0.00494698}, {0.223866, 
   0.00467467}, {0.224243, 0.00441613}, {0.2246, 
   0.00417077}, {0.22494, 0.00393804}, {0.225263, 
   0.00371741}, {0.225569, 0.00350833}, {0.225859, 
   0.00331029}, {0.226135, 0.00312278}, {0.226395, 
   0.00294532}, {0.226643, 0.00277742}, {0.226876, 
   0.00261862}, {0.227098, 0.00246849}, {0.227307, 
   0.0023266}, {0.227505, 0.00219253}, {0.227692, 
   0.0020659}, {0.227869, 0.00194631}, {0.228037, 
   0.00183341}, {0.228194, 0.00172685}, {0.228344, 
   0.0016263}, {0.228484, 0.00153144}, {0.228617, 
   0.00144196}, {0.228742, 0.00135758}, {0.228861, 
   0.00127803}, {0.228972, 0.00120303}}, {{0.2, 1.}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0.3, 0.2}, {0.1794, 
   0.1144}, {0.159364, 0.09969}, {0.149373, 0.0918938}, {0.143766, 
   0.0870708}, {0.140499, 0.0838085}, {0.138618, 0.081451}, {0.13761, 
   0.0796485}, {0.137177, 0.0781977}, {0.137134, 0.0769736}, {0.13736,
    0.0758964}, {0.137776, 0.0749139}, {0.138331, 
   0.073991}, {0.138987, 0.0731042}, {0.13972, 0.0722376}, {0.140513, 
   0.0713799}, {0.141353, 0.0705238}, {0.142233, 0.069664}, {0.143146,
    0.0687969}, {0.144089, 0.0679202}, {0.145059, 
   0.0670321}, {0.146053, 0.0661316}, {0.14707, 0.0652181}, {0.14811, 
   0.0642912}, {0.149171, 0.0633506}, {0.150252, 
   0.0623964}, {0.151354, 0.0614287}, {0.152476, 
   0.0604477}, {0.153617, 0.0594537}, {0.154777, 0.058447}, {0.155955,
    0.0574281}, {0.157151, 0.0563975}, {0.158365, 
   0.0553556}, {0.159596, 0.0543032}, {0.160842, 
   0.0532409}, {0.162105, 0.0521693}, {0.163382, 
   0.0510892}, {0.164674, 0.0500014}, {0.165978, 
   0.0489067}, {0.167295, 0.0478061}, {0.168623, 
   0.0467004}, {0.169962, 0.0455907}, {0.171309, 
   0.0444779}, {0.172665, 0.0433631}, {0.174027, 
   0.0422475}, {0.175395, 0.041132}, {0.176766, 0.0400178}, {0.178141,
    0.0389062}, {0.179517, 0.0377982}, {0.180892, 
   0.0366951}, {0.182266, 0.0355981}, {0.183637, 
   0.0345083}, {0.185003, 0.033427}, {0.186363, 0.0323554}, {0.187715,
    0.0312945}, {0.189057, 0.0302456}, {0.190389, 
   0.0292097}, {0.191708, 0.028188}, {0.193012, 0.0271814}, {0.194302,
    0.0261911}, {0.195575, 0.0252178}, {0.196829, 
   0.0242626}, {0.198063, 0.0233262}, {0.199277, 
   0.0224094}, {0.200469, 0.0215129}, {0.201638, 
   0.0206374}, {0.202782, 0.0197833}, {0.203902, 
   0.0189513}, {0.204996, 0.0181416}, {0.206063, 
   0.0173547}, {0.207102, 0.0165907}, {0.208114, 0.01585}, {0.209098, 
   0.0151326}, {0.210052, 0.0144385}, {0.210978, 
   0.0137678}, {0.211875, 0.0131204}, {0.212743, 
   0.0124961}, {0.213581, 0.0118948}, {0.21439, 0.0113161}, {0.21517, 
   0.0107598}, {0.215922, 0.0102255}, {0.216645, 
   0.00971291}, {0.217341, 0.0092215}, {0.218008, 
   0.00875084}, {0.218649, 0.00830045}, {0.219263, 
   0.0078698}, {0.219851, 0.00745836}, {0.220413, 
   0.00706558}, {0.220951, 0.0066909}, {0.221465, 
   0.00633372}, {0.221956, 0.00599348}, {0.222423, 
   0.00566958}, {0.222869, 0.00536143}, {0.223294, 
   0.00506845}, {0.223699, 0.00479005}, {0.224083, 
   0.00452566}, {0.224449, 0.00427469}, {0.224796, 
   0.00403661}, {0.225126, 0.00381084}, {0.225439, 
   0.00359686}, {0.225736, 0.00339413}}, {{0.4, 0.6}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0.2, 
   0.2}, {0.1456, 0.1456}, {0.12865, 0.12865}, {0.11991, 
   0.11991}, {0.11476, 0.11476}, {0.111523, 0.111523}, {0.109409, 
   0.109409}, {0.107996, 0.107996}, {0.107038, 0.107038}, {0.106382, 
   0.106382}, {0.10593, 0.10593}, {0.105616, 0.105616}, {0.105398, 
   0.105398}, {0.105247, 0.105247}, {0.105141, 0.105141}, {0.105067, 
   0.105067}, {0.105015, 0.105015}, {0.104979, 0.104979}, {0.104954, 
   0.104954}, {0.104936, 0.104936}, {0.104924, 0.104924}, {0.104915, 
   0.104915}, {0.104909, 0.104909}, {0.104905, 0.104905}, {0.104902, 
   0.104902}, {0.1049, 0.1049}, {0.104898, 0.104898}, {0.104897, 
   0.104897}, {0.104897, 0.104897}, {0.104896, 0.104896}, {0.104896, 
   0.104896}, {0.104896, 0.104896}, {0.104896, 0.104896}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}, {0.104895, 
   0.104895}, {0.104895, 0.104895}}}
set=ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True]
Show[set, Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large], Point[e0], Point[e1], 
   Point[e2], Point[e3]}]]
```

The output of this code is the figure below.

[image]

Instead of using the continuous line to represent the function, I would like to use arrows, similar to the figure below.
In addition, I would like to bring the points forward so that they are not hidden.
The corresponding image of what I am looking for is similar to the following.
P.s.  I tried using `ListVectorPlot` Plot and `ListStreamPlot`, but it didn't work.
[image]

can anybody help me?

Comment: You are probably going to have to build this up using Graphics primitives...

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2:** ***Show "only the arrows, without the filled line"***

**i.**  Use `Dashing[{0, 1, 0}]` to show only arrowheads:

```
llp /. Line -> Arrow /.  a_Arrow :> {Dashing[{0, 1, 0}], a}
```

[image]

**ii.** Use `"→"` as arrow head:

```
llp /. Line[x_] :> {LineColor -> White, 
   Arrowheads[{Automatic, #, Graphics[Text[Style["→", 14]]]} & /@ 
     Subdivide[If[ArcLength[Line[x]] < .5, 7, 15]]], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

**iii.** Partition line coordinates and skip some portions:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]

llp /. l : Line[x_] :> {Thin, Arrowheads[.015], 
   Arrow /@ 
     Partition[LineScaledCoordinate[x, #] & /@ N[Subdivide[100]],
          2, Round[Sqrt @ Length[x]]]}
```

[image]

Replace `2` with `5` in `Partition[...]` to get

[image]

**Update 1:** Using [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) + [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html)

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[BSplineFunction[#][t] & /@ data], {t, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[e0], Point[e1], Point[e2],
     Point[e3]}, 
  PlotStyle -> (Directive[Arrowheads[ConstantArray[.025, #]]] & /@ 
     Round[Sqrt @ Normalize[ArcLength /@ Line /@ data, Min]])] /. 
 Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
llp = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[ConstantArray[.02, 10]], 
  Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[e0], Point[e1], Point[e2],
     Point[e3]}] ;

llp /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you very much. How would the code look with only the arrows, without the filled line? How to bring the points to stay on top of the frame?

Comment: @SAC, please see the update re _"points to stay on top of the frame"_. I will update if i find a convenient way to show only the arrowheads.

Comment: @SAC, please see the update for a way to show only the arrows.